# is $D(\bar{\Omega})$ same as $C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$?

Tags: real-analysis

$D(\bar{\Omega})$ and $C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ are defined  as follows:
[image]

Comment: $D$ is smooth functions of compact support, yes?  So if $\Omega$ is unbounded then I think the indicator on $\Omega$ is in the latter but not the former.

Comment: I agree with Jason; at a minimum Evans uses this notation.